# ¿Como hago una expresión regular con RegExr en el que no pueden escribir '/' al principio o al final o 2 '//' consecutivos en un campo de entrada?

Tags: java, regex, validación, java-8, input

Me han pedido hacer una validación de caracteres especiales en la que los 2 inputs que hay en un formulario permiten el carácter "/" pero estos campos no deben comenzar o terminar con una barra inclinada '/' y no deben contener dos barras inclinadas consecutivas '//'

**tipos de entrada válidos**

- 1234567890123456
- bnm/gre
- info adicional blá?$$ blá

**tipos de entrada no válidos**

- /mas información
- mas//información
- mas información/

He hecho este código donde en las entradas no pueden poner '/' al principio al final y que no pueden ser consecutivas.

```
public void validarNotSpecialCharactersField20(String field20) {
        if (field20.startsWith("/") || field20.endsWith("/") || field20.contains("//")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El campo 20 no puede comenzar o terminar con '/' o contener dos '/' seguidos");
        }
    }

    // validar que el campo 21 no tenga dos '/' seguidos ni comenzar con '/' regexp: ^[^/]*$ y termine con '/' regexp: ^[^/]*$
    public void validarNotSpecialCharactersField21(String field21) {
        if (field21.startsWith("/") || field21.endsWith("/") || field21.contains("//")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El campo 21 no puede comenzar o terminar con '/' o contener dos '/' seguidos");
        }
    }
```

Pero ahora me han pedido que use regExr (https://regexr.com), y que haga este tipo de validación pero con una expresión regular, he estado atascado durante un par de días y realmente agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: Español, por favor. Ve a [edit] y traduce tu pregunta, incluyendo el título.

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya lo he hecho, muchas gracias por revisarlo.

Comment: @juandieruiz ¿Por qué `más información` es inválido?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Perdón el inválido es más//informacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente expresión regular coincide con una cadena que contenga cero caracteres o más y en la cual ni el primer carácter ni el último son `/` ni contiene dos caracteres `/` consecutivos:

```
^(?!\/)(?:(?!\/\/).)*(?<!\/)$
```

1. `^(?!\/)` Verifica que el primer carácter de la cadena no es `/`
2. `(?:(?!\/\/).)*`  Coincide con todos los caracteres antes de encontrar `//` o hasta agotar la cadena
3. `(?<!\/)$`  Verifica que la subexpresión anterior coincidió con todos los caracteres de la cadena y que el último carácter de la cadena no es `/`

Es posible que en algunas versiones o configuraciones no se reporte ninguna coincidencia si la cadena es vacía (si tiene cero caracteres).

Comment: Muchas gracias @JGomez